How to display a map within the flutter app instead of opening it in a web view
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

import 'package:zuri_health/models/hospital/hospital.dart';

class HospitalDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Hospital hospital;

  const HospitalDetails({
    Key ? key,
    required this.hospital
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(hospital.name ? ? 'Hospital Details'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FlutterMap(
              options: MapOptions(
                center: LatLng(
                  hospital.location!.latitude!, hospital.location!.longitude!),
                zoom: 13.0,
              ),
              layers: [
                TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate:
                  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                ),
                MarkerLayerOptions(
                  markers: [
                    Marker(
                      width: 80.0,
                      height: 80.0,
                      point: LatLng(hospital.location!.latitude!,
                        hospital.location!.longitude!),
                      builder: (ctx) =>
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.location_on,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                      'Address:',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(hospital.address ? ? 'Unknown Address'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      const Text(
                          'Services:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: hospital.services!.map < Widget > ((service) {
                            return Text(service.name ? ? '');
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I am trying to display the map within my Flutter App but am getting the following errors,which I have been trying to debug but am hitting a bottleneck.
The named parameter 'layers' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'layers'.
The method 'TileLayerOptions' isn't defined for the type 'HospitalDetails'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'TileLayerOptions'.
The method 'MarkerLayerOptions' isn't defined for the type 'HospitalDetails'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MarkerLayerOptions'.

I don't see _HospitalDetailsState in your code.

The HospitalDetails widget was changed from a statefull widget to a statesless, as I don't need to manage any internal state. Or do I need to?

Check the documentation of the package, maybe you try to use an older example. Currently there is no layers in FlutterMap class, urlTemplate is in TileLayer class etc.

Having checked the documentation, I had to change the named parameter 'layers[]' into children[], changed the method 'TileLayerOptions' into 'TileLayer' and method 'MarkerLayerOptions' into 'MarkerLayer'

I had to change the named parameter 'layers[]' into children[], changed the method 'TileLayerOptions' into 'TileLayer' and method 'MarkerLayerOptions' into 'MarkerLayer'


class HospitalDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Hospital hospital;

  const HospitalDetails({
    Key ? key,
    required this.hospital
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(hospital.name ? ? 'Hospital Details'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FlutterMap(
              options: MapOptions(
                center: LatLng(
                  hospital.location!.latitude!,
                  hospital.location!.longitude!,
                ),
                zoom: 13.0,
              ),
              children: [
                TileLayer(
                  urlTemplate:
                  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                  subdomains: const ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                ),
                MarkerLayer(
                  markers: [
                    Marker(
                      width: 80.0,
                      height: 80.0,
                      point: LatLng(
                        hospital.location!.latitude!,
                        hospital.location!.longitude!,
                      ),
                      builder: (ctx) => Icon(
                        Icons.location_on,
                        color: AppTheme.red,
                        size: 40.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                      'Address:',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(hospital.address ? ? 'Unknown Address'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      const Text(
                          'Services:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: hospital.services!.map < Widget > ((service) {
                            return Text(service.name ? ? '');
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



